Identifying a K'nex-like piece
I got this piece from a bulk lot of "rare" Lego parts (eg, some only appeared in one set). I assumed at first that it was Lego Znap, but I looked up Znap pieces and they don't seem to have any parts like this one: Znap has beams like K'nex does, and weird connectors, and only two kinds of axles which are different to this one. I think this piece is Lego though because the plastic is hard and good quality like Lego, and it's the exact same colour as dark bluish grey. I have no idea what it could be though since it looks like a small version of K'nex, but it's not Znap... Maybe the ends of the axle are meant for rubber bands?
The axle is slightly longer (~1mm) than 5 studs, and very slightly too big to fit in a hollow stud.



Just to be sure: I guess there are no visible markings - letters, numbers, logos?

@zovits It turns out it's just a Micro K'nex piece, but yes there are no markings at all

It is Micro K'NEX

It's a 40mm Grey Rod and here it is for sale on two unofficial K'nex reseller sites:

https://www.knexusergroup.org.uk/en/info_K509522.html
https://knexreplacementparts.com/product/gray-rod-40mm/


Oh wow, I had no idea micro K'nex was a thing! Obviously the piece looks like small K'nex but I didn't think it could actually be official K'nex!
